# How do I avoid the singularities during the calculation of an integral?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, special-functions

I face a serious problem when I try to calculate the following integral. My code is the following:

```
u = 0.9;

A[x_, t_] := Re[N[AiryAi[x - u*t + I*u*t - t^2]]*Exp[I*t (x - u*t - t^2 + u/2)]*
Exp[x - u*t - t^2]*Exp[I*(x - u*t)]]

A1[x_, t_] := A[x, t]* Conjugate[A[x, t]]

F[t_]:= NIntegrate[(D[Re[A1[x, t]], x])^2/Re[A1[x, t]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
Method -> "DoubleExponential"]

F[#] & /@ Range[0, 10];
```

Could anyone tell me how to overcome the warning messages?

Comment: are you sure you want to integrate from infinity to infinity? Would not this always give 0? In addition, you are doing numerical integration w.r.t. $x$, but there is a free variable $t$ in there.

Comment: @Nasser I am sorry. I meant "from -Infinity to Infinity". The integral is a function of t.

Comment: I thought that is what you meant, but the function you are integrating has non-numerical value $t$ in it. Hence not possible to do numerical integration, If you look at the integrand you will see this. So you need to give $t$ some numerical value before.

Comment: @Nasser However, if I use the Real part (Re[...]) of the integrand, then I can do numerical integration, right?

Comment: I do not think taking real part of Airy function will get rid of the $t$. Why do you think that is the case? I just tried `ComplexExpand@Re@AiryAi[Exp[x - u*t - t^2]]` and got back `AiryAi[E^(-((9 t)/10) - t^2 + x)]` so the $t$ is still there. It is also better to use `u=9/10` instead of `0.9` even though you are going to do numerical integration later on.

Comment: @Nasser Sorry again for the confusion. I do not want to get rid of t. As you can see my function F is a function of t. I just only want to integrate with regard to x, which is a numerical value.

Comment: `As you can see my function F is a function of t. I just only want to integrate with regard to x, which is a numerical value`. You can not do this. With numerical integration, the integrand itself can only have $x$ as symbol. But you have both $t$ and also $x$ as symbols. Try `NIntegrate[t*Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]` and see what happens. You will get an error. May be what you want to do is symbolic integration, but I doubt this will be successful as your integrand is very complicated.

Comment: @Nasser I do not agree. If I define a function F[t_] := NIntegrate[t*Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}] and then calculate for example F[5] I will not get an error.

Comment: hum.. but you are not doing this here. That is the point. In the example you show in your comment, you are giving a numerical value for $t$.  That what `F[5]` does. In the code you posted you are not doing this and so $t$ remains symbol. Any way, I think I said all I can on this. Hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: Another problem: you are taking the derivative of a function involving `Re`, which isn't analytic. Have a look at the nonsense `D[Re[A1[x, t]], x]` yields.

Comment: There's some problem with the real values. You define A as Re[something], so that A is real. Then you define A1 as A times the conjugate of A, but this is not necessary, since A is already real, maybe you wanted A squared? Finally in the integrand, again, you take real values of A1, but it's unnecessary, since A1 is real by construction.

Try to make sure the formula you write in Mathematica correspond exactly to what you want to calculate.

Comment: Please include the warning messages (message names at least). It aids others who are searching for help with a similar problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend going as far as possible with analytic calculations and only using numerics at the end. Especially numerical derivatives are notoriously difficult to calculate exactly.

Define the function $A$ without numerics:

```
A[u_, x_, t_] = AiryAi[x - u*t + I*u*t - t^2] * Exp[I*t (x - u*t - t^2 + u/2)] * Exp[x - u*t - t^2]*Exp[I*(x - u*t)];
```

Define its complex conjugate manually by replacing every `I` with `-I` (see elsewhere for details):

```
Ac[u_, x_, t_] = AiryAi[x - u*t - I*u*t - t^2] * Exp[-I*t (x - u*t - t^2 + u/2)] * Exp[x - u*t - t^2]*Exp[-I*(x - u*t)];
```

Define $|A|^2$ without using the `Re` operator:

```
A1[u_, x_, t_] = A[u, x, t]*Ac[u, x, t];
```

Define the integrand through analytic differentiation:

```
B[u_, x_, t_] = D[A1[u, x, t], x]^2/A1[u, x, t] // Simplify;
```

Now we can integrate without problems. Using `Re` to chop off very small imaginary parts (on the order of the machine precision),

```
Clear[F];
F[u_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := F[u, t] =
  Re[NIntegrate[B[u, x, t], {x, -∞, 0, t^2, ∞}]]
```

where I've added the intermediate integration points $x=0$ and $x=t^2$ so that `NIntegrate` is more stable; they were roughly estimated from plotting some examples of $B(u,x,t)$ and could be improved for better speed.

Check:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{t, F[9/10, t]}, {t, 0, 10}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Could you explain the necessity of using "?NumericQ" in the argument of function F ?

Comment: It's not necessary but ensures that the user does not abuse `F`. For example, asking for `F[a, b]` will not attempt any numerical integration work because `a` and `b` aren't numerical and the integration would fail anyway.